# User CMD Batch Interaction

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy

I am creating a batch file that will install files into a certain location on a computer. this could be used for various things such as game mods, folder backups, etc. If i am trying to have the user type in the path they want the file to be sent to. How would I do that? I would like to have that path pasted into a .txt file, that way i can access it later in the program. I have tried the ">" and it works on putting the path into the file. How do I extract that information. "Direct Question" How can I take user input, and use it to paste files somewhere else in the computer using the user's path that was specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many questions do you want for your money?

To input a string:

```
set /p "installdir=Install in which directory? "
```

At any point thereafter, you can use `%installdir%` to access the directoryname input.

If you need to save the directoryname in a file, then use

```
>"c:\wherever\you\want\filename.txt" echo %directoryname%
```

and to read it,

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("c:\wherever\you\want\filename.txt") do set "dirread=%%a"
```

or

```
set /p "dirread="<"c:\wherever\you\want\filename.txt"
```

and "pasting" or probably copying,

```
copy /b "x:\directory from\filename.whatever" "%dirread%\"
```

to copy the file "filename.whatever" from directory "x:\directory from\" to directory in the environment variable `dirread` as read by one of the previous two methods or substitute `directoryname` for `dirread` to use the directory name originally entered.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!